# Finding the position of a sound source using time difference of arrival (TDOA) in 2D

Tags: linear-algebra, triangulation

I am currently working on a project where i need to be able to find a sound source based on three microphones. The sound source is located between 15-20 meters away from the microphone array.

The microphones have set positions as $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$, $(x_3, y_3)$ and the distances between them are known.

If one define the sound sources position as $(x_p, y_p)$ and the time for the source to reach each microphone as $T_i$, it is possible to setup the three equations:

1. $\sqrt{(x_p -x_1)^2 +(y_p - x_1)^2} = c*T_1$
2. $\sqrt{(x_p -x_2)^2 +(y_p - x_2)^2} = c*T_2$
3. $\sqrt{(x_p -x_3)^2 +(y_p - x_3)^2} = c*T_3$

taking the time differences $T_2 - T_1$ , $T_3-T_1$ and $T_3- T_2$, we can set up

1. $ \frac{1}{c}( \sqrt{(x_p -x_2)^2 +(y_p - x_2)^2} - \sqrt{(x_p -x_1)^2 +(y_p - x_1)^2} )= T_2 - T_1$
2. $ \frac{1}{c} (\sqrt{(x_p -x_3)^2 +(y_p - x_3)^2} - \sqrt{(x_p -x_1)^2 +(y_p - x_1)^2} )= T_3 - T_1$
3. $ \frac{1}{c}( \sqrt{(x_p -x_3)^2 +(y_p - x_3)^2} - \sqrt{(x_p -x_2)^2 +(y_p - x_2)^2} )= T_3 - T_2$

Since $T_i - T_j$ are known, we have a set of three equations with two unknown. I am wondering how to solve the last one for $x_p$ and $y_p$, or alternatively find the angle from $(0,0)$ to $(x_p, y_p)$

Edit:
I have searched around and i see that the approach is typically sum of least squares, but i will still appreciate any help on how it works

Edit2: Forgot parenthesis on two of the equations

Comment: In your final set of equations, the $\frac 1c$ needs to multiply both radicals, not just the first one.

Comment: Thank you, edited now

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not enough information to derive a unique solution. To see this, note that if you add a fixed time $T_0$ to each of $T_1, T_2, T_3$, you are going to get the exact same time differences, and therefore, your final set of equations will be unchanged. But the original set will be changed and quite obviously the increased time would indicate a source that is farther away.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nonlinear least squares estimation to find the optimal solution. For this define
$$f_{ij}(u) := \sqrt{(x_p-x_i)^2+(y_p-y_i)^2} - \sqrt{(x_p-x_j)^2+(y_p-y_j)^2}$$
where $u^T := \begin{bmatrix}x_p & y_p\end{bmatrix}$. Create the Jacobian matrix as
$$J=\frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial u}$$
Now, starting from an initial location $u^*$ solve the equation
$$b=J|_{u=u^*}u$$
using least squares estimation where $b_{ij} = c(T_i - T_j)$. Now use this new solution as $u^*$ and solve the equation again until the solutions converge, i.e. solution is close the $u^*$. This way you can find the geometric center of the triangle, whose corners are the intersection of the parabolas defined by $f_{ij}$.

Comment: Thank you for answering!